# Errors in node_modules while trying to build for production

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, node-modules

There are several errors occurring when trying to build the application for production. But i don't get these errors while executing `ng build`. Errors occur only while attempting to execute `ng build --prod`. is there a way to fix the issue.
Thanks in advance.

````
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:245:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:70:21)
    at visitNodes (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15788:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16014:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:61:31)
    at visitNode (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15779:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15909:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:61:31)
    at visitNode (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15779:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15966:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:61:31)
    at visitNode (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15779:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15977:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:61:31)
    at visitNode (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15779:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15873:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:61:31)
    at visitNodes (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15788:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16023:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:61:31)
    at visitNode (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15779:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16021:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:61:31)
    at visitNodes (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-clientnode_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15788:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16016:24)
    at transformer (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:56:16)
    at /Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1354:86
    at reduceLeft (/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1066:30)
ERROR in chunk main [initial]
[name].[chunkhash:20].js
/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js??ref--7-0!/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
RuntimeTemplate.moduleId(): Module /Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js??ref--7-0!/Users/dhinendran/Documents/sample-client/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js has no id. This should not happen.```
````

Answer (score 1):

After a few research, found the answer in github.
Changing the `"buildOptimizer" : false` resolves the issue. It's under **Configuration->Production** in **angular.json**